# How to pass to view a form and a queryset in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, view, model

I'm still noob and Django and I'm not getting this issue.

I'm trying to send to a view a form and a queryset with all of my clients, however the queryset is not returned.

I'm doing this in trabalhos\views.py and the queryset is from a model in clientes\models

Can anyone help me? This is really breaking my head.

Thank you

```
def novotrabalho_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = novoTrabalho(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            codigo = form.cleaned_data['codigo']
            nome = form.cleaned_data['cliente']
            paciente = form.cleaned_data['paciente']
            dispositivo = form.cleaned_data['dispositivo']
            tecnico_responsavel = form.cleaned_data['tecnico_responsavel']
            

            c = trabalho(codigo=codigo, cliente=nome, paciente=paciente, dispositivo=dispositivo, tecnico_responsavel=tecnico_responsavel)
            c.save()



    form = novoTrabalho()
    listaclientes = cliente.objects.all()
    

    return render(request, "novotrabalho.html", {'form': form, 'listaclientes': listaclientes} )
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the queryset is not returned"?

Comment: I can't iterate the queryset in my view, the data is not there. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: well are there `clients`? Can you check if the database has `cliente` records, what does it print for `print(listaclientes)`?

Comment: Yes of course. I have several clients. If I return the listaclientes as an HttpResponse I got:
cliente object (1)cliente object (2)cliente object (3)cliente object (4)cliente object (5)cliente object (6)

Comment: well then you can iterate over these in the view, with `for cliente in listaclientes: print(cliente)` for example.

Comment: I can't. The queryset simply don't pass to view. By the way, even if I try to pass a stupid string variable its won pass...

Comment: to the view or the template. You here shared the view. The template is the `novotrabalho.html`.

Comment: Hello, Found the error...Was on the view...

My for was: { % for c in listaclientes %}

I fixed the issue correcting to: {% for c in listaclientes %}

Thanks for your help and time @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0):

Found the error...Was on the view... My for loop was: { % for c in listaclientes %} I fixed the issue changing to: {% for c in listaclientes %}